# package diagram for hadoop MR2

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I'm starting to learn hadoop MR and i believe it'd be easy to navigate and understand the classes provided by the framework if there is a package/class diagram available for it.

Could anyone please share if you got package diagram for MR2.

PS: I found the UML package & class diagram for MR1 but could not get for MR2. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. MR1 - <[MR1 UML](http://wcemtech2011.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/hadoop-mapreduce-class-diagram/)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to learn MR you don't need to deep dive into the internals. But if you want to
do so, I'd suggest you to check first the [YARN articles](http://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-apache-hadoop-yarn/) from Hortonworks to see the big picture. You may also read the architecture [design doc](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12486023/MapReduce_NextGen_Architecture.pdf) of YARN.
Then I'd have a look at the [javadoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/index.html) and would also check [this](https://bigdataexplorer.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/hadoop-yarn-rpc/) blog which dissects several components of the Hadoop stack including YARN.
You will also need to check out the Hadoop [source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/) from which you can generate UML
diagrams up to your taste. Several tools exis, e.g: [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/home).

Comment: Thanks @Lorand Bendig. The state machine diagrams were quite informative and also i'll try using the ObjectAid.